# Docker architecture for many PHP containers

Tags: php, docker, docker-swarm

I'm wondering what you guys think about how to architect Docker to handle many containers, each running different PHP code. Basically, each user on the system will have their own PHP code and code is not the same. Think of it like each user has their own wordpress site. (I think) This means I need to mount different directories for each php container.

What I initally thought of doing was to create a separate SERVICE for each user. This way, when an http request comes in, I can use host headers to find the right service to handle the request.

But then if the system has 1000 users, then that means having 1000 services - seems like a lot for Docker. I see some people running 1000 containers, but I wasn't sure about that many services.

Another thing is that I wanted to make a separate network for each user - this means 1000 networks - this is doable?

Am I going down a totally wrong path here?

Comment: What is purpose for this? I really do not get what you want when you use other php directory for each user? why cannot just use different controller?

Comment: This sounds like the same idea as shared web hosting. Why would every user have different PHP code? Also, if this is the case, why wouldn't every user be a different Docker image? Like the previous comment, it would help to have some more information about what these applications are doing and why there is a router / controller that would be directing requests to potentially 1000 different code bases.

Comment: Think of it like shared web hosting, yes. But using Docker - so that each individual account can scale their services. Each user has different php code to run. So I simply create a service for them and use haproxy to direct the web traffic. I've built this already and everything seems to work ok - but I'm not too sure how it will scale. What will happen when I have 1000 accounts, meaning 1000 services.  The docker image that runs can be the same in each case, but the php code is different, meaning I need to mount different directories for each account.  Same as hosting many Wordpresses.